# Remove rows from pandas dataframe with condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

import pandas as pd

```
### create toy data set
data = [[1111,'10/1/2021',21,123],
        [1111,'10/1/2021',-21,123],
        [1111,'10/1/2021',21,123],
        [2222,'10/2/2021',15,234],
        [2222,'10/2/2021',15,234],
        [3333,'10/3/2021',15,234],
        [3333,'10/3/2021',15,234]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns = ['Individual','date','number','cc'])
```

What I want to do is remove rows where Individual, date, and cc are the same, but number is a negative value in one case and a positive in the other case. For example, in the first three rows, I would remove rows 1 and 2 (because 21 and -21 values are equal in absolute terms), but I don't want to remove row 3 (because I have already accounted for the negative value in row 2 by eliminating row 1). Also, I don't want to remove duplicated values if the corresponding number values are positive. I have tried a variety of duplicated() approaches, but just can't get it right.

Expected results would be:

```
  Individual       date  number   cc
0        1111  10/1/2021      21  123
1        2222  10/2/2021      15  234
2        2222  10/2/2021      15  234
3        3333  10/3/2021      15  234
4        3333  10/3/2021      15  234
```

Thus, the first two rows are removed, but not the third row, since the negative value is already accounted for.

Any assistance would be appreciated. I am trying to do this without a loop, but it may be unavoidable. It seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43462153/remove-rows-from-pandas-dataframe-using-multiple-criteria), but I can't figure out how to make it work in my case, as I am trying to avoid loops.

Comment: Will the positive and negative values always be equal and zero out as in your example? And will other god rows ever be zero?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question that the positive and negative values that would count as duplicates (and thus removed) would be equal to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't be sure since you did not post your expected output, but you could try the below. Create a separate df called `n` that contains the rows with -ve 'number' and join it to the original with `indicator=True`.

```
n = df.loc[df.number.le(0)].drop('number',axis=1)
df = pd.merge(df,n,'left',indicator=True)

>>> df

   Individual       date  number   cc     _merge
0        1111  10/1/2021      21  123       both
1        1111  10/1/2021     -21  123       both
2        1111  10/1/2021      21  123       both
3        2222  10/2/2021      15  234  left_only
4        2222  10/2/2021      15  234  left_only
5        3333  10/3/2021      15  234  left_only
6        3333  10/3/2021      15  234  left_only
```

This will allow us to identify the Individual/date/cc groups that have a -ve 'number' row.

---

Then you can locate the rows with 'both'  in _merge, and only use those to perform a `groupby.head(2)`, concatenating that with the rest of the df:

```
out = pd.concat([df.loc[df._merge.eq('both')].groupby(['Individual','date','cc']).head(2),
           df.loc[df._merge.ne('both')]]).drop('_merge',axis=1)
```

Which prints:

```
   Individual       date  number   cc
0        1111  10/1/2021      21  123
1        1111  10/1/2021     -21  123
3        2222  10/2/2021      15  234
4        2222  10/2/2021      15  234
5        3333  10/3/2021      15  234
6        3333  10/3/2021      15  234
```

Comment: I added the expected output. What you have does not do it, but I see what you are doing and maybe can be edited to get the expected results.

Comment: if you change ```head(2)``` to ```head(1)```, gets your desired output. However, is that always going to be the case? Keeping the first two rows of the group that has a negative number? You will probably need to use ```sort_values``` with ```head``` to make sure it works. The data you provided is not enough to account for all the different scenarios however, which means that with ```head(1)```, you do get your desired outcome, but in your real data set it might not work. So please consider providing more information and more concrete examples.